# Desk home screen display appears randomly even when disabled

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 and every so often, without any apparent reason, while my phone is idle sitting on my desk (no dock or anything; it's just laying on my desk) the screen will light up and display the time and the icons of my any current notifications appear.

I have disabled daydream and unchecked "Desk home screen display"

It appears to happen randomly after device has been idle for some time. It's not a huge deal, but it's annoying and rather distracting.

My device  is a rooted Verizon Samsung Galaxy S4 running android 4.2.2 on baseband VUAME7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the air gesture settings and deselect "quick glance"

Answer (score 0):

There's some app running that requests a full WakeLock (which requires the screen to be on). You might use [WakeLock Detector](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wakelock-detector-save-battery/com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector) or [BetterBatteryStats](http://www.appbrain.com/app/betterbatterystats/com.asksven.betterbatterystats) to figure out which app that might be:

[image: WakeLock Detector] [image: BetterBatteryStats]
<sup>*WakeLock Detector* and *BetterBatteryStats* (source: Google Play; click images for larger variant)</sup>

Both apps show what app held WakeLocks in the past. WLD is available for free on Play, BBS for EUR 2. Once you've identified the culprit, you can either re-configure that app to avoid those WakeLocks – or check for a replacement with better behaviour ;)

Comment: I don't see the to review "Full wakelocks" in BBS. Just Kernal wakelocks and partial wakelocks.

Comment: They have no separate section. Think of "kernel wakelocks" as system-based and "partial wakelocks" as listed by apps. So just check for apps having caused wakelocks will limit the list of installed apps to those possibly causing the issue. Most likely candidates are those dealing with network stuff, e.g. checking network strength or want to transfer data in background.